# Angular components aren't being initialized after route navigation in Electron

Tags: angular, typescript, electron

I'm making a simple Angular CLI application in Electron (to learn more about both) which lists a set of story projects, and lets a user edit the plot of each in a text editor. Everything is working well except for one issue: Any time I try to navigate to a component by changing the route, the new component's HTML is displayed in the router outlet, and the component's constructor is called, but the OnInit method is never invoked.

I have two routes: A "Story List" route that displays a list of story projects, and a "Plot Editor" route that is meant to load after clicking one of the stories. As you can see, the Story List route is set up to display in the router outlet by default:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { StoryListComponent } from './story-list/story-list.component';
import { PlotEditorComponent } from './plot-editor/plot-editor.component';

const routes: Routes = [
                        {path: '', component: StoryListComponent},
                        {path: 'plot-editor/:title', component: PlotEditorComponent}];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is the HTML and Component for the StoryListComponent:

```
<div class="story-list-page">
    <div class="story-list-container">
        <div class="story-item" *ngFor="let story of stories" (click)="onStoryClick(story)">
            {{story}}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StoryDirectoriesService } from '../story-directories.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-story-list',
  templateUrl: './story-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./story-list.component.css']
})
export class StoryListComponent implements OnInit {

  stories: string[] = [];

  constructor(private storyService: StoryDirectoriesService,
              private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
              private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.storyService.storyDirectories.subscribe((value) => {
      this.stories = value;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    })
    this.storyService.getStories();
  }

  onStoryClick(title: string){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('plot-editor/'+title);
    this.cdr.detectChanges();
  }

}
```

Here you can see the strategy is to load the stories, create a UI element for each, and have the OnClick event navigate to the plot-editor route with the story's title as a route parameter.

Finally, here is the PlotEditorComponent:

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { StoryDirectoriesService } from '../story-directories.service';
import { PlotOption } from '../models/plot-option';
import { PlotPoint } from '../models/plot-point';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-plot-editor',
  templateUrl: './plot-editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./plot-editor.component.css']
})
export class PlotEditorComponent implements OnInit {

  plotPoints: PlotPoint[] = [];
  title: string = "";

  constructor(private storyService: StoryDirectoriesService,
    private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
    private route: ActivatedRoute) {
      console.log("Constructing Plot Editor Component!");


     }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log("Initializing plot editor");

    this.storyService.plotPoints.subscribe((value) => {
      this.plotPoints = value;
      this.cdr.detectChanges();
    })

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      console.log("Title: " + params['title']);
      this.title = params['title'];
      this.storyService.getPlotPoints(this.title);
    });
  }

}
```

The application correctly constructs and initializes the StoryListComponent:

[image]

However when I click a story the UI correctly swaps over to the PlotEditorComponent UI, and PlotEditorComponent is constructed, but the new component is never initialized. I know this because the console never logs the "Initializing plot editor" comment, which is the first instruction in OnInit:

[image]

The comment informing that the constructor has been called is logged, but nothing from inside OnInit.

This only happens for components that are navigated to. If I change my routing so that the plot-editor route is the default, then it is completely initialized upon loading the application. I have also tried removing the :title route parameter to see if a simpler route works, but the behavior is no different.

Any ideas what I'm missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Have you enabled cors on localhost?

Comment: I haven't done anything to configure cors - would that affect anything if I'm not making any network requests and am only switching components? Right now everything is just loading from disk.